# Authentication is required but no CredentialsProvider has been registered - GITLAB

Tags: java, git, authentication, gradle, gitlab

I'm working on a pipeline on Gitlab. Every time I execute it, publish stage fails. On details I get the error below.

this project is inside a group variables are inherited. I have verified the credentials for my Gitlab account and I don´t have issues to pull or push the project.

Important points:

- code in .yml file is working with other projects inside the group, the only change on this specific script is a path for artifacts and the value of a variable used for a name.
- we have tried using a different gitlab runner .
- verified that all variables used in the project can be reached.
- we have updated Gradle version and some plugins as well.
- using --info or --debug we don´t get any useful information.

has anyone had an issue like this one?

thanks in advance

```
``
:prepare FAILED
 FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
 * What went wrong:
 Execution failed for task ':prepare'.
 > Problem fetching from remote.
 * Try:
 Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
 * Exception is:
 org.gradle.api.tasks.TaskExecutionException: Execution failed for task ':prepare'.
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeActions(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:98)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.execute(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:68)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipUpToDateTaskExecuter.execute(SkipUpToDateTaskExecuter.java:62)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ValidatingTaskExecuter.execute(ValidatingTaskExecuter.java:58)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipEmptySourceFilesTaskExecuter.execute(SkipEmptySourceFilesTaskExecuter.java:88)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ResolveTaskArtifactStateTaskExecuter.execute(ResolveTaskArtifactStateTaskExecuter.java:46)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.execute(SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.java:51)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.execute(SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.java:54)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteAtMostOnceTaskExecuter.execute(ExecuteAtMostOnceTaskExecuter.java:43)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.CatchExceptionTaskExecuter.execute(CatchExceptionTaskExecuter.java:34)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskGraphExecuter$EventFiringTaskWorker$1.execute(DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.java:236)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskGraphExecuter$EventFiringTaskWorker$1.execute(DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.java:228)
    at org.gradle.internal.Transformers$4.transform(Transformers.java:169)
    at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:106)
    at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:61)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskGraphExecuter$EventFiringTaskWorker.execute(DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.java:228)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskGraphExecuter$EventFiringTaskWorker.execute(DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.java:215)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.AbstractTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker.processTask(AbstractTaskPlanExecutor.java:77)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.AbstractTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker.run(AbstractTaskPlanExecutor.java:58)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.process(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:32)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.execute(DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.java:113)
    at org.gradle.execution.SelectedTaskExecutionAction.execute(SelectedTaskExecutionAction.java:37)
    at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter.execute(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:37)
    at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter.access$000(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:23)
    at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter$1.proceed(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:43)
    at org.gradle.execution.DryRunBuildExecutionAction.execute(DryRunBuildExecutionAction.java:32)
    at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter.execute(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:37)
    at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter.execute(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:30)
    at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher$RunTasksAction.execute(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:230)
    at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher$RunTasksAction.execute(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:227)
    at org.gradle.internal.Transformers$4.transform(Transformers.java:169)
    at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:106)
    at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:56)
    at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.doBuildStages(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:161)
    at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.doBuild(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:112)
    at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.run(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:95)
    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.GradleBuildController.run(GradleBuildController.java:66)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.ExecuteBuildActionRunner.run(ExecuteBuildActionRunner.java:28)
    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.ChainingBuildActionRunner.run(ChainingBuildActionRunner.java:35)
    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.InProcessBuildActionExecuter.execute(InProcessBuildActionExecuter.java:41)
    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.InProcessBuildActionExecuter.execute(InProcessBuildActionExecuter.java:26)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.ContinuousBuildActionExecuter.execute(ContinuousBuildActionExecuter.java:75)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.ContinuousBuildActionExecuter.execute(ContinuousBuildActionExecuter.java:49)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.ServicesSetupBuildActionExecuter.execute(ServicesSetupBuildActionExecuter.java:49)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.ServicesSetupBuildActionExecuter.execute(ServicesSetupBuildActionExecuter.java:31)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ExecuteBuild.doBuild(ExecuteBuild.java:67)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.BuildCommandOnly.execute(BuildCommandOnly.java:36)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:120)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.WatchForDisconnection.execute(WatchForDisconnection.java:37)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:120)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ResetDeprecationLogger.execute(ResetDeprecationLogger.java:26)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:120)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.RequestStopIfSingleUsedDaemon.execute(RequestStopIfSingleUsedDaemon.java:34)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:120)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ForwardClientInput$2.call(ForwardClientInput.java:74)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ForwardClientInput$2.call(ForwardClientInput.java:72)
    at org.gradle.util.Swapper.swap(Swapper.java:38)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ForwardClientInput.execute(ForwardClientInput.java:72)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:120)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.LogAndCheckHealth.execute(LogAndCheckHealth.java:55)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:120)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.LogToClient.doBuild(LogToClient.java:60)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.BuildCommandOnly.execute(BuildCommandOnly.java:36)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:120)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.EstablishBuildEnvironment.doBuild(EstablishBuildEnvironment.java:72)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.BuildCommandOnly.execute(BuildCommandOnly.java:36)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:120)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.StartBuildOrRespondWithBusy$1.run(StartBuildOrRespondWithBusy.java:50)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.DaemonStateCoordinator$1.run(DaemonStateCoordinator.java:297)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ExecutorPolicy$CatchAndRecordFailures.onExecute(ExecutorPolicy.java:63)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.StoppableExecutorImpl$1.run(StoppableExecutorImpl.java:46)
 Caused by: org.ajoberstar.grgit.exception.GrgitException: Problem fetching from remote.
    at org.ajoberstar.grgit.operation.FetchOp.call(FetchOp.groovy:100)
    at org.ajoberstar.grgit.operation.FetchOp.call(FetchOp.groovy)
    at java_util_concurrent_Callable$call.call(Unknown Source)
    at java_util_concurrent_Callable$call.call(Unknown Source)
    at org.ajoberstar.grgit.util.OpSyntaxUtil.tryOp(OpSyntaxUtil.groovy:45)
    at org.ajoberstar.grgit.Grgit.methodMissing(Grgit.groovy:188)
    at org.ajoberstar.gradle.git.release.base.BaseReleasePlugin$_addPrepareTask_closure2_closure5.doCall(BaseReleasePlugin.groovy:58)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.AbstractTask$ClosureTaskAction.execute(AbstractTask.java:656)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.AbstractTask$ClosureTaskAction.execute(AbstractTask.java:637)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter$1.execute(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:115)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter$1.execute(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:109)
    at org.gradle.internal.Transformers$4.transform(Transformers.java:169)
    at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:106)
    at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:56)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeAction(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:109)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeActions(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:90)
    ... 70 more
 Caused by: org.eclipse.jgit.api.errors.TransportException: https://....: Authentication is required but no CredentialsProvider has been registered
    at org.eclipse.jgit.api.FetchCommand.call(FetchCommand.java:135)
    at org.eclipse.jgit.api.FetchCommand.call(FetchCommand.java:76)
    at java_util_concurrent_Callable$call$0.call(Unknown Source)
    at org.ajoberstar.grgit.operation.FetchOp.call(FetchOp.groovy:97)
    ... 85 more
 Caused by: org.eclipse.jgit.errors.TransportException: https:...: Authentication is required but no CredentialsProvider has been registered
    at org.eclipse.jgit.transport.TransportHttp.connect(TransportHttp.java:485)
    at org.eclipse.jgit.transport.TransportHttp.openFetch(TransportHttp.java:288)
    at org.eclipse.jgit.transport.FetchProcess.executeImp(FetchProcess.java:136)
    at org.eclipse.jgit.transport.FetchProcess.execute(FetchProcess.java:122)
    at org.eclipse.jgit.transport.Transport.fetch(Transport.java:1179)
    at org.eclipse.jgit.api.FetchCommand.call(FetchCommand.java:128)


``
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the plugin `org.ajoberstar.grgit` requires credentials in order to access the repository. Since none are configured, it raises an error as such.

The [documentation](https://ajoberstar.org/grgit/main/grgit-authentication.html#_http_basicauth_credentials) you can either use system properties to configure the credentials or an environment variable with an auth token.

Assuming environment variable, you will need to generate a token [here](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/profile/personal_access_tokens.html) and set that as `GRGIT_USER` environment variable.